# pgfplotstable - How can I stack the columns from a data file under one another without the headings but with additional vspace?

Tags: pgfplotstable

I'd like to typeset data in multiple columns below one another. The problem is, if I were to typeset lots of data for relatively few parameters, I'd like to typeset the content on a upright a4 page. In consequence I'd like to stack the columns in the back under the columns in the front. One could use several `\pgfplotstypeset` commands of course but then, what about the alignment and precise formatting? So this question is about trying to typeset it with one command, if possible. I am sure some of you may find this trivial but I have never used `pgfplotstable` before so I am a bit baffled.

Specifically I supplied some fake data file `data.txt` which I would like to typeset in a table with 7 columns.

The typeset table shall have **1** head row. It should have a first column which I want to fill with content myself (which would be AA, BB, CC,... in every fifth row). Then the columns `Word`--`ColHeadAA5` should follow. The content up to this point should be put up top. The data in the remaining columns ColHead1BB-ColHead5BB should be put below that. The columns which get put below shall not include their column headings, only the data. They should of course be put in the columns 3--7, not the first two columns.

It is noteworthy that this is of course an abstract example--one might expand this to plenty more columns "converted" into stacked "rows". I also intend to implement some booktabs formatting if I'll use this.

Is this even possible?

Little extra: between the stacked sets I'd like to have some additional vertical space inserted, something that roughly equals `\addlinespace[3pt]` of the booktabs-package.

### Example picture of what should be typeset

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
Word,ColHeadAA1,ColHeadAA2,ColHeadAA3,ColHeadAA4,ColHeadAA5,ColHeadBB1,ColHeadBB2,ColHeadBB3,ColHeadBB4,ColHeadBB5
A,17,19,15,17,3,8,14,7,8,14
B,10,8,11,15,10,8,6,13,13,10
C,20,5,16,12,8,5,16,7,14,17
D,14,4,10,14,16,14,5,10,5,11
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.txt}{\mydata}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns/Word/.style={string type}]{\mydata}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Either you will need to create a new table which is actually organized the way you want it printed, or you need to extract the contents of the table and create a tabular.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Actually chose to typeset the table by hand. Will leave this question open though.

Answer (score 1):

It's not difficult with `\pgfplotstablesave` to create to parts of the original table and `\pgfplotstablevertcat` to vertically concatenate those two parts.

You'll find the details in the comments of my code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableset{
% create aliases for correct merging
    alias/ColHeadAA1/.initial=ColHeadBB1,
    alias/ColHeadAA2/.initial=ColHeadBB2,
    alias/ColHeadAA3/.initial=ColHeadBB3,
    alias/ColHeadAA4/.initial=ColHeadBB4,
    alias/ColHeadAA5/.initial=ColHeadBB5,
% create first column with AA, BB, etc.
    create on use/Something/.style={
        create col/set list={AA,,,,BB,,,,}},
    columns/Something/.style={string type}
}

\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
Word,ColHeadAA1,ColHeadAA2,ColHeadAA3,ColHeadAA4,ColHeadAA5,ColHeadBB1,ColHeadBB2,ColHeadBB3,ColHeadBB4,ColHeadBB5
A,17,19,15,17,3,8,14,7,8,14
B,10,8,11,15,10,8,6,13,13,10
C,20,5,16,12,8,5,16,7,14,17
D,14,4,10,14,16,14,5,10,5,11
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
% Read your table
\pgfplotstableread[
    col sep=comma, 
    ]{data.txt}{\tableall}

% create table A with the fist 5 columns (and Word)
\pgfplotstablesave[
    columns={Word,ColHeadAA1,ColHeadAA2,ColHeadAA3,ColHeadAA4,ColHeadAA5},
    ]{\tableall}{tableA.out}

% create table B with the last 5 columns (and Word)
\pgfplotstablesave[
    columns={Word,ColHeadBB1,ColHeadBB2,ColHeadBB3,ColHeadBB4,ColHeadBB5}
    ]{\tableall}{tableB.out}

% load table A in a new table tablevertcat
\pgfplotstableread{tableA.out}{\tablevertcat}

% append the contents of table B to table A (tablevertcat)
\pgfplotstablevertcat{\tablevertcat}{tableB.out}

% and this is the final result
\begin{center}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns={Something,Word,ColHeadAA1,ColHeadAA2,ColHeadAA3,ColHeadAA4,ColHeadAA5},
    % add a little space every 4 rows
    every nth row={4}{before row=\addlinespace[4pt]},
    % booktabs rules
    every head row/.style={
        before row=\toprule,
        after row=\midrule
    },
    every last row/.style={
        after row=\bottomrule
    },
    columns/Word/.style={string type},
    % correct column numbers alignment
    multicolumn names,
    columns/ColHeadAA1/.style={string type,column type={S[table-format=2]}},
    columns/ColHeadAA2/.style={string type,column type={S[table-format=2]}},
    columns/ColHeadAA3/.style={string type,column type={S[table-format=2]}},
    columns/ColHeadAA4/.style={string type,column type={S[table-format=2]}},
    columns/ColHeadAA5/.style={string type,column type={S[table-format=2]}},
    ]{\tablevertcat}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]